# Add rows to pandas df using itterrows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas datframe

[image: 1]

For each country I wish to create as many rows as the number of years it exists.
For instance, the US will have 201 rows, Canada 95 and so forth.

I thought of doing something like:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    for range(row['styear'], row['endyear']):
        df.append(row)
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column with the `range` of years, and then `explode` that column

```
# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['United States', 'Canada', 'Bahamas', 'Cuba'],
    'styear': [1816, 1920, 1973, 1902],
    'endyear': [2016, 2016, 2016, 1906]
})


df['allyears'] = [range(start, end+1)
    for start, end in zip(df.styear, df.endyear)]
df = df.explode('allyears')
print(df)
```

Output

```
          country  styear  endyear allyears
0   United States    1816     2016     1816
0   United States    1816     2016     1817
0   United States    1816     2016     1818
0   United States    1816     2016     1819
0   United States    1816     2016     1820
..            ...     ...      ...      ...
3            Cuba    1902     1906     1902
3            Cuba    1902     1906     1903
3            Cuba    1902     1906     1904
3            Cuba    1902     1906     1905
3            Cuba    1902     1906     1906

[347 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you @RichieV.  It worked flawlessly. I now wish to do something more complicated. For each year in "all years" and for each country, I want to to create as many rows as the number of countries that exists in the world at that year. For instance, in 1970, the US will have 100+ rows, with an additional column of country x name. One for Cube, one for Israel etc. The same will be true for Germany for the same year. Of course, this will also apply for them in 1971, 1972 and so forth.

Comment: That looks like a product, but it is hard to picture just by your comment, perhaps you can create a new question for that... you should attempt to do it yourself before posting another question